# Linux app (non-GUI) for benchmarking bitmining server's perfomance

Tags: linux, server

Is there a Linux application that can benchmark the bitmining perfomance of a headless server ?

The application could run from the shell (terminal).

*Up to know I have found [this](http://bitminter.com/test) that requires Java.*

Comment: Any miner itself will be fine for testing the performance of a specific server.